# Как создать свой обработчик формы авторизации?

Tags: symfony2

Основная задача: необходимо авторизоваться под другим пользователем.
При этом мы находимся на домене, а  авторизоваться надо на поддомене (для поддоменов написан отдельный файл security и в целом там всё полностью автономно). К слову сказать, поддоменов при этом может быть сколь угодно много.
Использовать параметр `switch_user` с ролью `ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH` при таком раскладе не получается.

В итоге было решено использовать подставную форму аторизации.
Т.е. для авторизации на поддомене реализованы две формы:
Первая - стандартная: логин, пароль. Этот вариант работает.
Вторая - не стандартная. Вместо пароля нужно заполнить два поля: ключ и дополнительный код.

Главный вопрос: как можно реализовать обработку второй формы?
Было бы здорово, если бы можно было вклинить в `login_check` свою дополнительную проверку для второй формы. Но судя по документации, обработка формы происходит автоматически и создать свой контроллер `login_check`, увы, не получается.

Но должна же быть возможность добавить в форму авторизации свои поля и соответственно по своему их обработать?
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае подставная форма авторизации была не лучшей идеей. 
Всё можно решить на много проще и быстрее.

Авторизацию по другим пользователем можно сделать с помощью генерации Token'a для нужного ид.

Идея взята отсюда: [How to simulate Authentication with a Token in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html)